# Add Class based on content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some html mock up like so:

I want to add an additional class of `title`, `content`, `button`to my cta-module div based on its children div.

Would really appreciate some help with this initial part.

```html
<!-- Add Class Title, Content, Button to cta-module-->
<div class="cta-module">
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>

<!-- Add Class Title & Button to cta-module-->
<div class="cta-module">
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please post [mcve] of the problem you are facing.

Comment: What are the rules you by which you want to add the classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".cta-module").children().each(function() {
  $(this).closest(".cta-module").addClass($(this).attr('class'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add Class Title, Content, Button to cta-module-->
<div class="cta-module">1
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>

<!-- Add Class Title & Button to cta-module-->
<div class="cta-module">2
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

1. Loop through all child of `.cta-module` using `.each()` then get the current item using `this` context and get it class using `.attr('class')`.
2. Add the class to parent `.cta-module` using `.addClass()`

Comment: @Arun glad to help mate

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the children of `cta-module` and get the class for each of them and apply it to the closest `cta-module`

Reason why i hardcoded `.children(".title, .content, .button")` is that if it has some other element with a class, that would otherwise be added to the parent also. This way we only get `title, content and button` . If you want all, just use `.children()`

```js
$('.cta-module').children(".title, .content, .button").each(function() {
  var getclass = $(this).attr("class");
  $(this).parent().addClass(getclass)
})

console.log($('.cta-module:eq(0)').attr("class") + " | " + $('.cta-module:eq(1)').attr("class"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add Class Title, Content, Button to cta-module-->
<div class="cta-module">
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>

<!-- Add Class Title & Button to cta-module-->
<div class="cta-module">
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```